# Allow user to ssh to server without having local account

Tags: ssh, radius, rhel7

I have a pam_radius module set up on a rhel7 server.  A user with a local account is able to ssh into the server with the radius login information.

I was wondering if it is possible to allow a user to authenticate to the radius server, and if it is successful, have a shell session open on the rhel7 server.

Another option would be to have the server create a user account for the authenticated user.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to allow authentication is to configure your sssd daemon with your pam modules. Check [here](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/03/13/new-sssd-features-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-1/) and [here](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/03/13/new-sssd-features-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-1/) to see how. Moreover, you can block unwanted users (including local accounts, or restricting access) in either /etc/security/access.conf, or /etc/ssh/sshd.conf.

Finally, the pam modules themselves can be edited to support this in /etc/pam.d but it is **VERY IMPORTANT** that you read the man pages, because messing around with pam modules without understanding is a great way to lock yourself out of a server. I've done it more times than I'd care to admit when I was integrating AD :)

Comment: If you're going anywhere near PAM modules, have a root shell open, and make sure you have a backup of any file you think you might change. You will _almost certainly_ need that root shell to revert a typo or other "silly" misconfiguration. And don't close it until you have proven you can still log in...

Comment: ^ good advice. Forgot to mention it but this has saved me before as well. I have been bitten by these once or twice each.

Comment: @goris29 - if this answers your question, please mark as answered :) If not, I'm happy to elaborate to explain further if you need me to.